# Insert data in a form inputbox with jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

In my main page, I have a div showing some external html content. Here I have some radio buttons. When the user select a radio, the form of the parent page shound be updated.

The external code is like this:

```
function updateForm(val){
  $('#photourl', window.parent.document.frm).val(val).change();
};
...
<input name="photo" id="photo" value="someVal" onclick="updateForm(this.value)" type="radio">
```

It works fine in firefox, opera, flock, msie. **It does not work at all in chrome and safari**.

Anybody can help me?
Thanks

Comment: the external page is contained in an iframe?

Comment: if a page in an iframe, you can try with window.top

Comment: no... 
the external page is loaded in a div:
<div id="box">Some text</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the second argument in `$('#photourl', window.parent.document.frm)` is acquired with a nonstandard technique.  try `$('#photourl', $('#frm', window.parent.document)[0])`, or, because it's all in one document really (per your comments), just get rid of it.

Comment: $('#photourl', document.frm).val(val).change();

Now it works! Thanks :-)